# Best way to store authentication token

Tags: security

What is the best and secured way to store authentication token in web and mobile application ?

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"? Which architectures are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

In the mobile store the token using the UserDefault in iOS and SharedPreference in Android. Likewise in the web use cookies to store data.

Reference for UserDefaults: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults

Reference for SharedPreference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults

Reference for cookies: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm